# Valgrind throwing unexplainable error in thread

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp, valgrind

I'm having trouble identifying why valgrind is throwing this error:

```
==82185== Thread 2:
==82185== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==82185==    at 0x401B9A: proc_outconnection_thread (station.c:401)
==82185==    by 0x4E3CDF4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==82185==    by 0x51471AC: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==82185==
the pass im sending is 'this'
==82185== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==82185==    at 0x401BCA: proc_outconnection_thread (station.c:403)
==82185==    by 0x4E3CDF4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==82185==    by 0x51471AC: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so) 
==82185==
```

As a bit of background information, the program i'm trying to create in C simulates a train station that uses TCP connections as "trains".  I'm trying to get the program to use threads in order to both listen for and try and connect to other stations (other instances of the program).

The problem seems to exist when passing an internal data struct to a thread creation function via an argument struct that contains a pointer to the internal data struct.  This way each thread has a pointer to the programs internal data.

In my efforts of testing, the file is compiled with 
`gcc -pthread -g -o station station.c -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99`

To produce my error, begin an instance of station with `valgrind ./station tom authf logfile 3329 127.0.1.1`
and then begin another instance with `valgrind ./station tim authf logfile 3328 127.0.1.1`

Due to an if statement in main, the station name with tim will attempt to connect to tom, and tom will create a socket and listen for tims attempt to connect.  The connection seems to be successful however for some reason I'm also unable to flush the connection to send anything between, which i have a feeling may be because of what Valgrind is telling me. 
What's so strange is that when a thread is created for the connection on tom's instance, no errors in valgrind are thrown despite having a very similar procedure for creating the thread (the same arguments are passed through the argument pointer and the same assignments are made).

Could it be a false positive for tim's end, or am I doing something severely wrong here?

Comment: don't link to source code. Break your code down into digestable size that still has the same problem and show it to us.

Comment: compiling the code under ubuntu linux 14.04 using `gcc`, with parameters `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std-c99` results in a long string of warning messages.  Strongly suggest fixing those warnings.   The warnings about the unused variables and unused parameters are just signs of sloppy programming, but other warnings, such as those about the bad parameters to some calls to fprintf() are more severe  Note: lines 403 and 405 (in my editor) contain the fprintf() warnings.

Comment: there are several `magic` numbers in the posted code.  `magic` numbers make code much harder to understand and are a real headache when performing maintenance.   Strongly suggest inserting a enum or #define's for those numbers, with meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the returned value from fgets() (and similar I/O statements) needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.   When communicating via a socket, as the code does, it is much better to use `send()` and `recv()` rather than `fprintf()` and `fgets()`

Comment: Strangely my compiler with the added -Wextra isn't showing this long list of warnings that yours is showing, would you be able to show me the warnings you are receiving for lines 403 and 405?  And I was somewhat under the assumption that using a filestream for for communication would be easier but I guess it's possible that they could be causing the problem.

Comment: regarding this line: `conStation.clientName = malloc((strlen(buffer) + 1) * sizeof(char));`   when calling malloc() multiplying the parameter by the expression `sizeof(char)` has absolutely no effect and just clutters the code. (sizeof(char) is defined as 1 in the C standard)

Comment: here are the warnings for lines 405 and 407:  `405:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wfomat-security] fprintf(conStation.clientCon, internal->stationAuth);`   and   `407:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arugments [-Wformat-security] fprintf(conStation.clientCon, internal->stationName);`  Note: I prepended the file with `#define _POSIX_SOURCE` to get rid of a warning about `fdopen()`  which moved everything down a couple of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is passing pointer on local variable into thread function. Simplest workaround is declare this variable as static or global, but this is not good if there are several threads use that variable.
Its better to allocate needed memory size for structure, initialize and pass this into thread function:

```
ArgStruct *argStruct = malloc(sizeof(ArgStruct));
if(argStruct == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cant alloc memory!\n");
    exit(98);
}
argStruct->internalStruct = internal;
argStruct->clientCon = fdopen(fd, "r+");
pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, proc_outconnection_thread, (void *)argStruct);
```

Also, don't forget to free this memory (at the end of `proc_outconnection_thread()` for example).

Comment: Thank you very much! This has fixed the problem, I had the wrong idea and thought that just having a pointer to the local variable would be enough to have other threads use it.

Answer (score 2):

Track the value of your `internal` data structure back to where it comes from and you will see that it originates from a `struct` object that is not initialized. You later assign values to some of the fields, but not to all.

**Always** initialize `struct` objects, and at the same time watch that you have a convention that makes it clear what default initialization (as if done with `0`) means for the type.

*If*, one day, you really have a performance bottleneck because your compiler doesn't optimize an unused initialization, think of it again and do it differently. Here, because you are launching threads and do other complicated stuff, the difference will never be measurable.

Comment: I've initialized all my structs (setting all members to null) and am still running into the issue however with valgrind claiming it's reading uninitialized bytes in the struct.  You have made a very good point though